# "to stick" im Deutschen

Tags: english-to-german

Im Englischen kann man in vielen Fällen das Verb "to stick" benutzen, um zu zeigen, jemand/etwas kann nicht aus irgendeinem Grund weiter geht.

Zum Beispiel;

Hardware (was Greifbares)

> My computer gets **stuck** when connected to the internet

Anwendung (was Ungreifbares)

> Windows 7 update **stuck** at "checking for updates"

Gehirn (was Ungreifbares)

> What to do when your brain gets **stuck**

Hals (was Greifbares)

> I feel something **stuck** on my throat

Ich wollte wissen, was die passendeste Übersetzung für "to stick" auf Deutsch ist?

Comment: What does "What to do when your brain gets stuck" mean? I only found references to having an obsessive compulsive disorder.

Comment: English is not my mother tongue but in my mother tongue, "my brain gets stuck" can also be said. For example, you study for an exam for 5 hours in row and your brain does not accept new information because of that fact that it is tired. In this case, you can say **my brain gets stuck**, I cannot learn anymore.

Comment: A "stuck brain" simply means that you can no longer think, regardless of the reason.  Another similar, funny expression is to have a "stupid attack," where the lack of thinking produces a result or action that is unintended and clearly wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die beste Übersetzung in den genannten Fällen wäre für mich das Kompositum **hängen bleiben** oder **hängenbleiben**

Die Übersetzung der Beispiele wäre dann:

> Mein Computer **blieb hängen** als ich ihn mit dem Internet verband
>
> Windows **blieb** bei der Prüfung nach Updates **hängen**

Das nächste Beispiel passt leider nicht so gut, aber mir fällt auch nicht wirklich was passenderes im deutschen Sprachgebrauch ein. Ich habe "Brain" mit dem mehr generischen "Gedanken" übersetzt, weil es sonst für einen Muttersprachler etwas komisch klingt:

> Was soll man tun, wenn die Gedanken **hängen bleiben**

und zu guter letzt:

> Ich fühle, dass etwas in meinem Hals **hängen geblieben ist**

Comment: Ist sicherlich in Ordnung die Uebersetzung. Auch möglich wäre in jedem der Fälle: "stecken bleiben".

Comment: Es ist humoristisch zu sagen, dass jemandes Gehirn hängengeblieben ist.

Comment: @Ethunxxx im Hals ganz sicher. Steckenbleiben passt aus meiner Sicht aber eher in Fällen, wo tatsächlich ein physikalischer Vorgang stattfindet, bei dem etwas durch eine Engstelle muss.

Comment: Ja, ich stimme Timbo zu, steckenbleiben kann man zwar auch verwenden, aber es hat doch eher einen Bezug zu einer physischen Präsenz.

Comment: z.B ich habe eine Aufgabe zum Erledigen aber aus irgendeinem Grund geht es nicht weiter. In so einem Fall kann man auch sagen; Ich bin bei der Aufgabe hängengeblieben?

Comment: Mit Computern benutze ich gewoehnlich "aufhaengen", zB "Mein Computer hat sich mal wieder aufgehaengt".

Comment: @Ad Infinitum: Ja, das wäre perfektes deutsch, das so sehr oft verwendet wird. Oliver: Ja, an "aufhängen" dachte ich auch, aber das passt eben nicht universell zu den anderen beiden Beispielen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine detaillierte Antwort. Im Alltag brauche ich irgendwie ständig dieses Verb :)

Comment: @TorstenLink Die Suche nach universellen Übersetzung ist in aller Regel auch unmöglich. Und wenn es keine gibt, dann sollte das die Antwort sein. Und im Bezug auf die vier Beispiele da oben, gibt es keine, denn mindestens ein Beispiel ist sehr, sehr holprig.

Comment: @Em1: Ja, es ist richtig, das es häufig keine universelle Übersetzung gibt. Aber trotzdem kommt meine Antwort dem so nahe, dass jeder verstehen würde, was gemeint ist (trotz holpern).

Answer (score 2):

Beim Thema "brain" kann man auch sagen: "Tut mir leid, da hatte ich gerade einen Hänger!" = Aussetzer/Gedanke ist hängen- bzw. steckengeblieben (womit wir wieder im gleichen Wortfeld wären)

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der duetschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] der Seite nehmen. Beachte, dass wir kein Forum mit Diskussionskultur, sondern eine strikte Fragen- und Antwortseite sind. Deine »Antwort« erscheint mir wenig mehr als ein Kommentar. Mehr Informationen darüber, wie die Seite funktioniert, gibt dir das [Help].